# Django - Selecting multiple entries from a JSON object to be shown on next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, django-views

I am attempting to allow multiple entries to be selected from a JSON object which is represented in an HTML table. Once the user has selected their entries and submitted, they will be redirected to a new page with only their selected entries shown in the table for them to confirm their selections.

One option is to create a function in my views.py that stores the selected entries in a list, the list is then called on the next page. To do this i would need my table to be a form, and on click of each row in the table that rows values get added to the list. I would also need to remove the item from the list if the user clicked that row again.

another option is to create a Javascript Set, and to then store that set somehow and represent it in the next page.

Does anybody have some advice on which if these would be the most practical to achieve at scale?

**An example of my data**

```
[
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "Description": "Pizza",
        "Price": "100.00"
    },
    {
        "pk": 2,
        "Description": "Cheeseburger",
        "Price": "80.99"
    },
    {
        "pk": 4,
        "Description": "Coca Cola",
        "Price": "20.00"
    },
    {
        "pk": 5,
        "Description": "Water",
        "Price": "15.00"
    }
]
```

Example usecase:

A user selects the Pizza and Water, and then submits their selection. on the next page only the pizza and water are displayed.

Any advice would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

create check boxes of values of pk (like 1, 2, 3)

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="name_anything"  id="c1"  title="title 1">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="name_anything"  id="c2"  title="title 2">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="name_anything"  id="c3"  title="title 3">
```

then in **views.py**

You can get the response with this:

```
response = request.POST.getlist('name_anything')
```

this will give a list of checked values like `['1', '3']` if first and last value were selected. Then assuming your mail list is this:

```
main_list = [
    {
        "pk": "1",
        "Description": "Pizza",
        "Price": "100.00"
    },
    {
        "pk": "2",
        "Description": "Cheeseburger",
        "Price": "80.99"
    },
    {
        "pk": "4",
        "Description": "Coca Cola",
        "Price": "20.00"
    },
    {
        "pk": "5",
        "Description": "Water",
        "Price": "15.00"
    }
]
```

**pk is string ("1") not integer (1)**

define a blank list:

```
new_list = []
```

and do this:

```
for i in main_list:
    if i['pk'] in response:
        new_list.append(i)

print(new_list)
```

**new_list** contains selected items (if 1st and 2nd boxes were selected.).

```
[
    {
        "pk": "1",
        "Description": "Pizza",
        "Price": "100.00"
    },
    {
        "pk": "2",
        "Description": "Cheeseburger",
        "Price": "80.99"
    },
]
```

Answer (score -1):

understand you need make a paginator in django if there is where you want see that **https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/**